# In R how do I compare values in a row of a dataframe by a single value in the same row of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, compare

I have two tables as follows:

```
mydata<-data.frame(ID=1:50,value=runif(n=50))
head(mydata)
```

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.59057316 |
| 2 | 0.11036060 |
| 3 | 0.84050703 |

The other is a dataframe comprising 50 rows and 100 columns of random numbers:

```
rntable<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=5000, min=0, max=1),nrow=50))
head(rntable)
```

| n | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.21092575 | 0.68144251 | 026929378 | 0.34583023 |
| 2 | 0.42875037 | 0.09916910 | 0.46925 | 0.6598 |
| 3 | 0.13268998 | 0.11890256 | 0.1718 | 0.31178 |

The requirement:

- Compare each row of rntable to the value in the same row of mydata
- Where the values of rntable are lower than mydata$value, output 0, else 1

The output should be a third table that looks like this:

| n | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Importantly, the comparison is per row.

I imagine I have to loop by row. But I don't know if I should first merge the tables (and if I did, column names would get messy). Is there an easy way in R to run this comparison?

I tried the following overly simple comparison but the output was all 1's.

```
x<-ifelse(rntable<mydata$value,0,1)
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use `data.frame(sapply(rntable, function(col) +(col < mydata$value)))`

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by playing with the code:

```
datac<-rntable #simple way to copy table structure

for(i in 1:nrow(mydata)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(rntable)) {
    datac[i,j]<-rntable[i,j]<mydata[i,2]  
  }
}
```

This results in the table as required.

Comment: Since R is vectorized, you could remove the first loop and simplify it to `for(j in 1:ncol(rntable)) { datac[,j] <- rntable[,j] < mydata[,2] }`.